# Android Fingerprint authentication

Tags: android, fingerprint

I am looking the android example "Fingerprint Dialog" http://developer.android.com/samples/FingerprintDialog/index.html in order to add a fingerprint authentication in my app.
Everything is working fine, but is there a way to check which one of the fingerprints saved into the phone has been used to authenticate the operation?

I need this in order to authenticate a specific user and not everyone has enrolled a fingerprint into the phone.

Comment: you can't do that. You can only check whether there was a finger authenticated or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to know which fingerprint was used in the authentication. Think about it this way, if the user gave someone a permission to enroll thier fingerprint, it means the other person is probably very close to the user and will have access to your content anyway.

On a side notice, you can be rest assured that if a new fingerprint will be added **after** the key creation, it will invalidate the previously created key.